# How to match a java enum

Tags: java, enums

I've an enum like this:

```
public enum ChartType
{   
    TABLE(0, false), BAR(1, false), COLUMN(3, false)
    private int type;
    private boolean stacked;
    ChartType(int type, boolean stacked)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.stacked = stacked;
    }
    public int getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public boolean isStacked()
    {
        return this.stacked;
    }
}
```

I get a charttype (int values like 0,1,3) from the request and want the matching input

Comment: If your enum `type`s matched their zero-based declaration sequence, you could do `ChartType.values()[desiredType];`. Otherwise there are a couple of workable solutions in the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a enum factory method out of a unique instance value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404840/create-a-enum-factory-method-out-of-a-unique-instance-value)

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines. Not sure if syntax is 100 percent, but it demos the idea.

```
public ChartType getChartypeForValue(int value)
    for(ChartType type : ChartType.values()){
        if(type.getType()  == value){
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution than mine :)

Comment: Small optimization could be creating `private static ChartType[] values = ChartType.values();` array and using it in your method, instead of recreating new array by `ChartType.values()` with each method call.

Answer (score 5):

You can add map in your enum to store relationship between `type` and specific enum value. You can fill it once in static block after all values will be created like:

```
private static Map<Integer, ChartType> typeMap = new HashMap<>();

static{
    for (ChartType chartType: values()){
        typeMap.put(chartType.type, chartType);
    }
}
```

then you can add method which will use this map to get value you want, or null if there isn't any

```
public static ChartType getByType(int type) {
    return typeMap.get(type);
}
```

You can use it like

```
ChartType element = ChartType.getByType(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create a static method to retrieve a type by number. With just a few charts like this, it's simplest to do that by just running through all the options. For larger enums, you could create a map for quick lookup. The only thing to watch for here is that any static initializers aren't run until *after* the values have been created.

Simple approach:

```
public static ChartType fromType(int type) {
    // Or for (ChartType chart : ChartType.getValues())
    for (ChartType chart : EnumSet.allOf(ChartType.class)) {
        if (chart.type == type) {
            return chart;
        }
    }
    return null; // Or throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define new method:

```
public ChartType valueOf(int id) {
   switch(id) {
   case 1:
      return TABLE;
   case 2:
      return BAR;
   case 3:
      return COLUMN;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Example:

```
ChartType.valueOf(1) // TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use java 8, use stream() and filter()

```
int value =2;
Optional<ChartType> chartType = Arrays.asList(ChartType.values()).stream().
filter(c -> c.type == value).findFirst();
if(chartType.isPresent()){
      ChartType chartType =chartType.get();
     //
}
```

Comment: Though this might work in theory, it's such a heavy-handed solution I would classify it as purely theoretical.